# Integer square root

Tags: reinventing-the-wheel, clojure, numerical-methods

This essentially performs the same function as `exact-integer-sqrt` in [`math.numeric-tower`](https://github.com/clojure/math.numeric-tower).

```clj
(defn isqrt
  "Returns the greatest integer less than or equal to the principal square root
  of n."
  [n]
  {:pre [(not (neg? n))]}
  (let [n (bigint n)]
    (if (zero? n)
      n
      (loop [x (.shiftLeft BigInteger/ONE (quot (inc (.bitLength n)) 2))]
        (let [y (quot (+ x (quot n x)) 2)]
          (if (<= x y)
            x
            (recur y)))))))
```

I'm interested in any improvements to this code. Some specific questions:

- Should the precondition be thrown explicitly as an `IllegalArgumentException`?
- Is it a bad idea to shadow the parameter with a `let` binding?
- Should the initial guess be more explicit about the calculation it is performing by using `Math.ceil` and `BigInteger.pow` instead of `inc`/`quot` and `BigInteger.shiftLeft`?

Comment: A small comment, I think `isqrt` is not a good name for your function (at first I thought it read `issqrt` and thought, "that must be a predicate"). Perhaps consider renaming to `int-sqrt` or something like that.

Comment: @PinCrash Are you sure? `isqrt` is the [standard name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) for this function.

Comment: I did not realize that, my bad. Number theory is not my strong suit.

Comment: @PinCrash No problem; I appreciate the feedback regardless. It may very well be better to use a longer name in this case; `math.numeric-tower` does, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

- No, unless you really want to have a specific type of exception thrown
  (to be able to catch and analyse it later).  It's a programmer error
  to call this function with negative values, so this solution is fine.
- No, unless you really really care about it.  However, the fact that
  the function returns a bignum all the time *should* be documented and
  is also a cause for concern IMO, since conversion to bignums isn't
  free.
- Yes, please, for exactly those reasons.  Do you incur a performance
  penalty with those functions?  Otherwise there's little reason not to
  use them.

Otherwise looks very good I'd say.

Comment: About the performance: on my machine, `(time (run! isqrt (repeatedly 1000000 #(Math/pow 2 (rand Long/SIZE)))))` takes 2300 milliseconds with the solution in the question, 2800 milliseconds using `Math.ceil` and `BigInteger.pow`.